# Mybatis handle multiple resultsets

Tags: mybatis

I have a stored procedure which produced 2 large result sets that would cause memory issue if stored in a list. I tried to use ResultHandler but I don't know how it can be applied to both result sets. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I used mybatis-spring-boot-starter in my project.

The statement called in `mapper.xml`:

```
<resultMap id = "result0" type = "java.util.LinkedHashMap">
<resultMap id = "result1" type = "java.util.LinkedHashMap">
<resultMap id = "result2" type = "java.util.LinkedHashMap">
<select 
  id = "findResultSet" 
  parameterType = "java.util.Map"
  resultMap = "result0, result1, result2"
  statementType = "callable">
  { call ${procedureSchema}.${procedureName}
    <foreach collection="procedureList" item = "item" index = "index" 
    open = "(" close = ")" separator=",">
      <if test = "item.type == 1">
        #{item.value,mode=IN}
      </if>
      <if test="item.type == 2>
        #{item.value, mode = OUT, jdbcType= VARCHAR}
      </if>
    </foreach>
  }
</select>
```

The corresponding method in mapper class:

```
void findResultSet(Map<String, Object> map, MyResultHandler 
myResultHandler);
```

The called method in mapper class:

```
MyResultHandler myResultHandler= new MyResultHandler();
mapper.findResultSet(map, myResultHandler);
```

`MyResultHandler` class:

```
public class MyResultHandler implements ResultHandler {
   @Override
   public void handleResult(ResultContext resultContext){
       logger.debug("rawData",resultContext.getResultObject)
}
```

I just implemented the base minimum to see if resultHandler pick anything up, and it didn't. The procedure contains just three simple select statements, each produces a different result set, and it worked fine when I store the results in a list and the result set was relatively small.

Comment: Your `ResultHandler` is called for both, so you can do something like... `Object obj = resultContext.getObject(); if (obj instanceof X) { ... `.
If you need further help, please add more info (procedure definition, mapper, classes, config, etc.) or share a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I added some details, donno if it helps tho.

Comment: Ah...universal mapping. Sorry, it may not be possible to use `ResultHandler` with that. I know you think that 'one mapper statement for all' is a great idea, but it really isn't. You should define separate statement and use POJO for each object instead of `Map` especially when the number of results is large.